# Why is MSDTC involved?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, transactions, msdtc

As far as I know, The MSDTC only gets involved when:

- You're querying a view/table inside a transaction that is linked to
  another server.
- You're using two SqlConnections (or whatever it is
  NHibernate uses) within a single TransactionScope
- You're enlisting another transactional component (like MSMQ or the transactional file system) inside a TransactionScope.
- Other situations not mentioned.

If I disable MSDTC and run the following code, I get (MSDTC on server 'Server' is unavailable) an error.

```
public bool Add(PurchaseOrderInfo purchaseOrderInfo)
{
    using (TransactionScope ts = new TransactionScope())
    {
        using (SqlConnection Cnn = new SqlConnection(SqlHelper.ConnStr))
        {
            Cnn.Open();

                try
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(/*Tr*/Cnn, "spPurchaseOrderAdd", purchaseOrderInfo.ExpectedShipment.ShipmentID, purchaseOrderInfo.CreateDate, purchaseOrderInfo.CustomerNotes, purchaseOrderInfo.Status, purchaseOrderInfo.PurchaseOrderNumber))
                    {
                        if (rdr.Read())
                            FillPurchaseOrderInfo(rdr, ref purchaseOrderInfo, GettingDepthEnum.Level_0);
                        else
                        {
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    foreach (PurchaseOrderDetailInfo detailInfo in purchaseOrderInfo.Details)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Test");
                        //if (!AddPurchaseOrderDetail(Tr, purchaseOrderInfo, detailInfo))
                        {
                            //Tr.Rollback();
                            return false;
                        }
                    }

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
                ts.Complete();
            }
        }
    }
```

Am I missing anything?

**Update**:
The stored procedure contains a simple insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO tblPurchaseOrder
(ShipmentID, CreateDate, CustomerNotes, PurchaseOrderState, PurchaseOrderNumber, LastActivityDate)
VALUES
(@ShipmentID, @CreateDate, @CustomerNotes, @PurchaseOrderState, @PurchaseOrderNumber, GETDATE());

--Step 2: return row that INSERTED to Client Computer.
SELECT dbo.viwGetPurchaseOrderWeight.Weight,* FROM tblPurchaseOrder LEFT OUTER JOIN viwGetPurchaseOrderWeight ON viwGetPurchaseOrderWeight.PurchaseOrderID =  tblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderID WHERE (tblPurchaseOrder.PurchaseOrderID = Scope_Identity());
```

**UPDATE2:**
When shutting down the MSDTC, the exception is thrown when the execution reached to this line:

```
using (SqlDataReader rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(/*Tr*/Cnn, "spPurchaseOrderAdd", purchaseOrderInfo.ExpectedShipment.ShipmentID, purchaseOrderInfo.CreateDate, purchaseOrderInfo.CustomerNotes, purchaseOrderInfo.Status, purchaseOrderInfo.PurchaseOrderNumber))
```

which means the subsequent lines has no effect.

Comment: What are your procs doing?  Do they involve linked servers?

Comment: @DavidHoerster I updated the question to include the procedure.

Comment: Do you have a second db connection being used?  It doesn't appear to be that, but I believe that if a second connection is introduced within the `TransactionScope`, then the transaction gets promoted to the DTC.  Otherwise it should stay local.

Comment: @DavidHoerster that is exactly what confuses me!! there is no other connection! SqlHelper is a class from Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data assembly, and I don't think it is opening a connection internally !!

Comment: It is easier getting answers if you post a stripped down code sample. Try to get rid of all the debug cruft.

Comment: is viwGetPurchaseOrderWeight by chance a vuew? Maybe it has a linked table.

Comment: @usr I updated the question, and clarified that the exception is thrown before all the debug cruft :)

Comment: @HLGEM the view is just a simple query that queries two table on the same database and same server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the stack trace, it appeared that the SQLHelper class is opening a connection to get the list of required parameters for stored procedure from database:

```
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteTransactionManagerRequest(Byte[] buffer, TransactionManagerRequestType request, String transactionName, TransactionManagerIsolationLevel isoLevel, Int32 timeout, SqlInternalTransaction transaction, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isDelegateControlRequest)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.GetDTCAddress(Int32 timeout, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.GetDTCAddress()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.Enlist(Transaction tx)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.Activate(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.ActivateConnection(Transaction transaction)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.DiscoverSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSetInternal(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Boolean includeReturnValueParameter)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelperParameterCache.GetSpParameterSet(SqlConnection connection, String spName)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationBlocks.Data.SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(SqlConnection connection, String spName, Object[] parameterValues)
   at AlefTextileProduction.SQLServerDAL.PurchaseOrder.Add(PurchaseOrderInfo purchaseOrderInfo)
```

I'm trying to find a solution around this !!

Answer (score 2):

Just be sure not open again the connection,

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope()) {
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
    connection.Open();
    connection.Close();
    connection.Open(); // escalates to DTC
      }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the relation to the question is. This code would, of course, promote, but he knows that. He wants to know why *his* code promotes.

Answer (score 1):

According to your post with the stack trace the EntLib class is opening another connection. We need to exclude it from the transaction. Wrap your call to `ExecuteReader` in a suppressing transaction scope:

```
SqlDataReader rdr;
using (var tsSuppress = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Suppress))
    rdr = SqlHelper.ExecuteReader(...)
```

This will momentarily set `Transaction.Current` to null so that the new connection does not pick up the transaction.

As a side note, the stack trace allowed us to find the root cause of the problem.

Comment: will suppressing the transaction prevent the insert procedure from being part of it? if so, I can't suppress the transaction, as the whole method should succeed or fail as one part.

Comment: Commands are never part or not part of a transaction. Connections are. The connection was auto-enlisted when you opened it because Transaction.Current was not null at this point. It stays in the tran forever, no matter what you do.

Answer (score 0):

In looking through the code of `SQLHelper` it looks like if you use the overload of `ExecuteReader` that takes `SqlParameter` instances instead of just the parameter values, then you'll save the step where `SQLHelper` tries to figure out what parameter maps to what value - and thereby saving a second trip to the database and the second connection and the promotion of your transaction to the MSDTC.

According to the [code I'm looking at](http://icodesnip.com/snippet/vbnet/sqlhelper-microsoft-application-blocks-for-net-code-snippets), this is the method you probably should call:

```
Public Overloads Shared Function ExecuteReader(ByVal connectionString As String, _
                 ByVal commandType As CommandType, _
                 ByVal commandText As String, _
                 ByVal ParamArray commandParameters() As SqlParameter) As SqlDataReader
```

If that doesn't work, then I'd suggest you roll your own DAL.  :)

Hope this helps.